# NodeJS / JavaScript if statement not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined, typeof

NodeJS (latest).

I have the following code. Why the first IF statement is not working as expected? The control doesn't go inside first IF statement.

I see valid console.log output for the first line in the following code and was expecting the first IF statement should execute its code too. But it doesn't; the 2nd IF statement works.

```
  console.log("-- inside create IP() qData['osType'] is set to :: " + qData['osType'])
  //--
  if ( qData['osType'] == 'undefined' ) {
    console.log("1 -- setting qData['osType'] = Linux by default for now. This should happen automatically.")
    qData['osType'] = 'Linux'
    console.log("1 -- inside create IP() if-statement-qData['osType'] and qData['osType'] is set to :: "+qData['osType'])
  }
  if ( typeof qData['osType'] == 'undefined' ) {
    console.log("2 -- setting qData['osType'] = Linux by default for now. This should happen automatically.")
    qData['osType'] = 'Linux'
    console.log("2 -- inside create IP() if-statement-qData['osType'] and qData['osType'] is set to :: "+qData['osType'])
  }
  qData['osType'] = 'Linux'
  //--
```

Comment: It would help to know what your `qData` object looks like

Comment: um,  because `qData['osType'] != (typeof qData['usType'])`

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Node.js, this is just standard JS behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I agree nnnnnn it's JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're checking for undefined-ness you can do one of:

- `typeof foo === 'undefined'`
- `foo === undefined`
- `foo === void 0`

Anything else is not actually (strictly) checking for an undefined value (including comparing a value directly with the string `'undefined'`).

Comment: didn't know if === was valid. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

In your first if statement, `qData['osType']` evaluates to `undefined`, but your comparison is checking whether `undefined == "undefined"`. The string literal has a value and therefore isn't equal to `undefined`.

In your second if statement, `typeof qData['osType']` evaluates to the string `"undefined"`, so the expression evaluates to `true` and your code block is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think 
`qData['osType'] == 'undefined'`
must be rewrite as 
`qData['osType'] == undefined`

My prefer to check

```
if(!qData.osType)
```

Comment: That's not really equivalent, since that conditional evaluates to `true` for other values, including `0`, `false`, and `''`.

Comment: Even `== undefined` will also be true if `qData.osType` is `null`.